# How to retrieve failed data in Sqoop while importing?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

I have importing 10 records form RDBMS to Hadoop thru Sqoop, job getting failure while 7th record loading here how can I retrieve last three records alone in next time. Can anyone help me with syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use --last-modified or --incremental-append to get those 3 rows only and this can be done only when you have id of that particular row (7th row in your case).

Please look at the command given below which brings newly added records to you after that particular timestamp. In your case if you pass id of 7th row, you'll get the next 3 rows from this command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname --username root --password cloudera --table tablename --target-dir /user/cloudera/new_directory_name -m 1 --check-column column_name --incremental append --last-value "2018-10-19 20:46:33"
```

Comment: Hi Anmol, Thanks for your inputs I am saying 7 records for an example, if the job getting failed in between and we not aware how many records loaded, in this scenario what would be the solution?

Comment: In that case we can simply create one shell script that can fetch last row id from hive table and store it into a variable, by passing that variable to the sqoop command we can load the rest of the records.

Comment: can we run this command in case of more then 1 mapper, then the dataset will be divided in multiple chunks ?

Comment: @vikasmalik yes we can.